# Is sender id unique in facebook messenger bot?

Tags: php, facebook-messenger

I am developing facebook messenger bot.I get sender id using following code.Is sender id unique or not?

```
 $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true, 512);

 $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Sender Id is unique for each user for each FB page.

From Messenger Platform Webhook Reference( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference):

> When representing a user, these IDs are page-scoped IDs (PSID). This
>   means that the IDs of users are unique for a given page.